# how to create a system generated file layout

Tags: sql-server, file, layout, ssis, export

Is there anyway to produce a file layout during the export of data from sql-server?
Normally I create manual file layouts, but i'd like to create a system generated layout.

thanks

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by a system generated file layout?

Comment: hi billinkc, what i mean is when i'm exporting a file using the wizard, i can pick options like delimited, etc... is there a way to also create the layout file that comes from ssis or some 3rd party tool. so the layout will say exactly what was produced, like 30000 rows, comma delimited, col1, col2, .... I normally hand produce these, but someone said that could include human error, which in the past it has. So i'm trying to give them something the system says it created.